# PySpark: GroupBy and count the sum of unique values for a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a device_id's event data which might be successful sometime and unsuccessful sometime.

| device_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Successful |
| 1 | UnSuccessful |
| 1 | UnSuccessful |
| 1 | UnSuccessful |
| 1 | Successful |
| 2 | Successful |
| 2 | UnSuccessful |
| 2 | UnSuccessful |

Is there a way to do a group by and get result for an Id in a single row like this:

| device_id | success_count | unsuccessful_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

I have been trying several ways using group by but I haven't been able to get the success_count and unsuccessful_count for a device_id in single row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group your data by device id and then pivot by status and count:

```
df.groupBy("device_id").pivot("status").count()
```

Comment: I somehow get classCast exception: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1604.showString.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType (org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType and org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')... Any Idea why it might happen ?

Comment: I'm accepting the answer since the above issue that I see is just related to my usecase and the solution actually does what I had asked for .